# Can I use Youtube API3.0 to build my application in TV?

Tags: web-applications, video, youtube-api, playback

We want to use Youtube API3.0 to build an application running on TV based on linux platform,just as MTK platform.the function including curate and surface videos,also including playback videos use Youtube embedded Players.
can I do it?
Thank u!